# turn single column .csv file into a list variable

Tags: python, list, csv, variables

I have a single column .csv file that I'd like to turn into list variable. How do I do that? Here's my code and the output I'm getting:

```
import csv
kws = open('kws.csv')
kws = csv.reader(kws)
for i in kws:
    print(i)
```

The output reads ['free games'] ['games now'] but I want it to read ['free games', 'games now'] so that I can create a list variable.

Answer (score 3):

For a single-column cvs file, you do not need the `cvs` module:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as fil:
    kws = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fil]
```

or

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as fil:
    kws = fil.read().split('\n')
```

Comment: It is better to use `rstrip()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
import csv

with open('kws.csv', 'r') as f:
    str_list = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f)]
```